# Android Activity refernce getting null on low memory

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory, android-activity, low-memory

I have an activity that contains a fragment , and this fragment plays youtube videos using android youtube api and I register an event listener for the youtube video when it finishes.
On the `onVideoEnded` event I get a reference to the activity to do something some action and this is how I get the activity inside my fragment :

```
private Activity theActivity;
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        theActivity = (Activity) context;
    }

    /*
     * Deprecated on API 23
     * Use onAttachToContext instead
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            theActivity = activity;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        theActivity = null;
    }

protected Activity getTheActivity() {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null)
            return activity;
        else return this.theActivity;
    }
```

As you can see on my `getTheActivity` method I check first the `getActivity` method , and if it returns a null value , I get the variable I got from `onAttach` when the fragment was created.
However on devices like samsung `getTheActivity` method still returns null !
I think it's probably a low memory issue !
How can I get a reference to my activity under any circumstances from my fragment ?

Comment: Is the activity visible at that point? Or are you talking about some edge case?

Comment: @azizbekian i can't really know , since i'm getting these reports from crashlytics !

Comment: The callback might have been called at a point, when user has moved the activity into background. You have no guarantees that the instance of the hosting activity will be there at that point.

Comment: I think if the user moved the activity into the background it would have been destroyed , since i'm using in my manifest android:noHistory="true" @azizbekian

Comment: `if the user moved the activity into the background it would have been destroyed` Not quite true. Activity will be destroyed in case system decides to kill the process. Do you pause your youtube video when user navigates away from the application?

Comment: @azizbekian i don't pause it manually in my code , however the video pauses yes , i think it's handled in the youtube library it self!

Answer (score -2):

Add these two lines in your manifest file in the application tag

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
 android:largeHeap="true"
```